# Reading xml with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, dom

I would like to read this xml with jQuery or something else if easier.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Film SYSTEM "film_commentaries_opinion.dtd">

<Film lang="fr" title="Mixed" originalTitle="">
 <Actors>
 </Actors>
 <Comments>
  <Comment>films adapted from comic <Tag length="5" />books have had plenty
    of success, whether they're about superheroes (batman, superman, spawn), 
    or geared toward kids (casper) or the arthouse crowd (ghost world), but 
    there's never really been a comic <Tag length="4" />book like from 
    hell before. For starters, it was created by Alan Moore 
    (and Eddie Campbell), who brought the medium to a whole new level in the 
    mid '80s with a 12-part series called the watchmen.</Comment>
 </Comments>
</Film>
```

Of course I cannot change the xml given by my rich emperor-client, and **of course what I want to retrieve is the word "*books*" and the word "*book*". `<Tag />` gives me a "*length*" which represents the length of the following word I need to pick.**

How can I do that?

For now I use :

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET', url: 'data/mergedXML_PangLee.xml.tag.xml', dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml) {
        var tags = $(xml).find("Tag");
        // other code here...
    }
```

Comment: You missed the part where you ask the question

Comment: I want to retrieve the word "books" and the word "book". How can I do that?

Comment: are the tags inside comment tags only ?

Comment: Yes there are : `<Comments><Comment><Tags>1</Tags>....<Tags>n</Tags></Comment></Comments>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery way

```
success: function(xml) {

    var liveXml = $(xml),
        inTagMode = false,
        tagLength,
        tags = [];

    liveXml.find('Comment').contents().each(function(){
        var node = $(this),
            value = node.text();

        if (inTagMode){
            tags.push( value.substring(0,tagLength) );
            inTagMode = false;
        } else {
            if (this.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'tag'){
                inTagMode = true;
                tagLength = node.attr('length');
            }
        }
    });

}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/wtykx/

---

The regular expression way (*assuming that the tags are full words*)

```
success: function(xml) {
    var regex = /(?:<tag.*?\/>)(..*?\b)/gi;
    var tags = [], result;
    while(result = regex.exec(xml)){
        tags.push(result[1]);
    }
}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/wtykx/1/

Comment: That is a great and clean code! I'll use the jQuery way as now, Tags are expression (many words), but thanks, it is great!